# PhpStorm + Xdebug remote debugging froze

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have set PHP debugging with Xdebug on PhpStorm to hit a localhost. Everything works fine with "smart PHP listening" or manual debug run unless I have got to the point where code looks like

```
$aOptions = array (
        'http' => array (
                'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n$sBits",
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query ( $aData )
        )
);

$rContext = stream_context_create ( $aOptions );
$sResult = file_get_contents ( $sUrl, false, $rContext );
return \json_decode ( $sResult );
```

and got stuck on a line

`$sResult = file_get_contents ( $sUrl, false, $rContext );`

with an error message

`file_get_contents(http://localhost:8888/data/?/Ajax/&amp;q[]=/0/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!`

but when I run debug after that line will pass all work fine.

PhpStorm and Xdebug has already set

- Settings | PHP | Debug | Max simultaneous connections --> 5.

`xdebug.remote_autostart = 1`

Any clue why Xdebug hangs on it when without debugging it can pass w/o any issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on JetBrains documentation for [simultaneous debugging sessions](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Simultaneous+debugging+sessions+with+PhpStorm) I was able to get it fixed by adding suggested code to start debugger session for child requests as follow

```
$aOptions = array (
        'http' => array (
                'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n$sBits",
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query ( $aData )
        )
);

$debuggingQuerystring = '';
if (isset($_GET['XDEBUG_SESSION_START'])) { // xdebug
     $debuggingQuerystring = '?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=' . $_GET['XDEBUG_SESSION_START'];
}
if (isset($_COOKIE['XDEBUG_SESSION'])) { // xdebug (cookie)
     $debuggingQuerystring = '?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM';
}

$rContext = stream_context_create ( $aOptions );
$sResult = file_get_contents ( $sUrl.$debuggingQuerystring, false, $rContext );
return \json_decode ( $sResult );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling localhost also in the `file_get_contents()` call.  Is it the same port?  If the xdebug is kicking in there too, then that request will be held (won't complete) and eventually the file_get_contents will time out.

Is that code also accessible from PHP Storm?  If so, you should jump in to that.  Otherwise try running with cookie-triggered xdebug, so only the main request triggers it.

`xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` means *When this setting is set to 1, Xdebug will always attempt to start a remote debugging session and try to connect to a client, even if the GET/POST/COOKIE variable was not present.*[1] so that indicates it might be this

I think you just want `xdebug.remote_enable = 1` then use the extension/plugin for your browser (most browsers have an enable/disable xdebug plugin) to trigger xdebug only on your main request

[1] https://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Comment: Yes - it is the same port as main instance where I run Xdebug, which runs on port 9000. And how I can run with cookie-triggered Xdebug? I'm using Xdebug Helper for Chrome